# Jquery and hex colors?

Tags: jquery, css

I can't set a color if I retrieve the hex code color from a html text. It works fine if I set the color manually.

html

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
   <div class="html-element-color">#ccff00</div>
   <div class="wrapper">hello</div>
</div>
<div class="main-wrapper">
   <div class="html-element-color">#cccccc</div>
   <div class="wrapper">hello</div>
</div>
<div class="main-wrapper">
   <div class="html-element-color">#f1f1f1</div>
   <div class="wrapper">hello</div>
</div>
```

This code works fine

```
$( ".html-element-color" ).each(function( index ) {

  var bgColorWrapper = "#ccff00";

   $(this).parent().find("div.wrapper").css( "background-color", bgColorWrapper ) ;

})
```

;

Here the code which doesn't work:

```
$( ".html-element-color" ).each(function( index ) {

  var bgColorWrapper = $('.html-element-color').text();

   $(this).parent().find("div.wrapper").css( "background-color", bgColorWrapper ) ;

});
```

Comment: you need to provide context to `$('.html-element-color')`, otherwise you're going to be getting .text() from the wrong elements...

Comment: Use camel case or snake case notation for names involving characters that are not allowed per JavaScript variable naming conventions.

Comment: @holodoc done (updated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bg-color` is an invalid variable name. Variable names cannot contain dashes. Try this instead.

```
$( ".html-element-color" ).each(function( index ) {

  var bgColor = $('.html-element-color').text();

   $(this).parent().find("div.wrapper").css( "background-color", bgColor ) ;

});
```

Also, it is likely that you want to set the color from the same element, but your intention is unclear from your post. Maybe this is what you *actually* want:

```
$( ".html-element-color" ).each(function( index ) {

  var bgColor = $(this).text();

   $(this).parent().find("div.wrapper").css( "background-color", bgColor ) ;

});
```

Comment: This is not the problem, I updated my question. I changed to 'bgColorWrapper'

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging. If you add  `console.log(bgColorWrapper);` after setting the variable, what does it output in your developer console?

Comment: Almost done. Your second code works, but now all the 'div.wrapper' get the last color which is '#f1f1f1'. How can I make that each  'div.wrapper' get the right color, which is the 'html-element-color' of the same level?

Comment: My mistake; everything is fine. Thanks.